# How can I output a matrix in Octave?

Tags: matrix, printf, octave

I got 2 files, the first one is the master, that calls the second one. 
So, I want to output a matrix created in the second file, while runs the first file, I guess via printf in the master file maybe??

I've tried this way and didn't work, besides the fact that shows the rows in the place of columns:

```
    printf("[%f; %f; %f]\n",r)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, especially the "master and second file" part. Are you refreing to a script file which calls another script file? Why don't use function and return the matrix as usual? Btw, you can output a matrix simply by calling `disp(yourmatrix)`

Comment: Yes, both are script files... I don't know what do you mean with usual? I'm new in Octave, I've tried with `disp(yourmatrix)` in both files, but didn't work... I just want to print the matrix for debugging..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want debugging output (and especially inside a loop) you initially disable the pager with `more off` and then use `disp(of_course_you_have_to_add_the_name_of_your_matrix_here)` or just mention the variable without trailing ; or remove the trailing ; at the assignment

```
more off
for k=1:2
  a = rand(2) * k;  # remove trailing ;
  a                 # or mention it without ;
  disp (a)          # or use disp which doesn't show the variable name
endfor
```

which outputs

```
a =

   0.80112   0.53222
   0.48930   0.56336

   0.80112   0.53222
   0.48930   0.56336
a =

   1.30374   1.85382
   0.30519   0.42486

   1.30374   1.85382
   0.30519   0.42486
```

See that a is displayed twice: once with "a = " and once without

Answer (score 4):

Create the following files in your current folder.

```matlab
%%% in file: second.m

A = [1,2;3,4];    % adding a semicolon suppresses the output
```

```matlab
%%% in file: master.m

% run 'second.m' script - this will add A on the workspace, since
% running this script is as if you had dumped the file's contents here
second    

% call the value of A without a semicolon to show contents on screen
A
```

Then from your octave terminal, run the 'master.m' script:

```matlab
master
```

This will display the contents of `A` on screen.